# How to organize helper functions

Tags: java, android, string, helpermethods

I need to create lot of helper routines for converting strings.

Something like :

```
String Function1(String s) {}
```

I would like to call them from any `Activity`.

What is the best way to do this ? Do I need to create a class or not ? I was thinking just to have one separate file with all these functions. Is this a candidate for a package or not ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a class with public static methods, then you can call them every where with     ClassName.methodName(parameters):

```
public class Util {
  public static String methodOne(String param) {
      //do something
      return param;
  }

  public static String methodTwo(String param) {
      //do something
      return param;
  }

  //...
}
```

Inside other classes:

```
String someString = Util.methodOne("Some String");
// ...
```

Comment: What about the `code` which relies on another class and static modifier is a weaker type than the code?

Comment: Why should be the methods static and not non-static?

Comment: @karlihnos If you use static methods, you can call them without instantiating Util class. For example: Util.methodOne("some string"). Otherwise you have to create a object of Util class and then call its methods: Util u = new Util(); u.methodOne("some string");

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad Thxs. This is clear to me. But is it the only reason to decide using statics methods against non-static? only because of the instantiation?

Answer (score 5):

```
Package: util
Class: StringUtils
Methods: all static
```

That is what I would do (and actually always do).

You can and should differ between the types. Normally you group stuff like `DateUtils`, `StringUtils`, `AndroidUtils`, `MathUtils` etc...

Comment: Thanks for the files organization, I made it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a utility class and I always put my utility classes in a com.xxx.xxx.util package.