# How to call a method from a helper class?

Tags: java, helper

I have a class with the name CommonSteps.java which contains the following method:

```
    @Then("^the following error is displayed: \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void the_error_is_displayed(String message) throws Exception {
    // although using the login page to retrieve - these will return if visible from any page!
    message = errorHelper.generateErrorMessage(message);
    assertThat(runtimeState.loginPage.getErrors(), hasItem(containsString(message)));
}
```

I would like to call this method into another class in an assertion. I have written the following code so far :

```
    @Then("^an upload invoice error message is displayed$")
public void an_upload_invoice_error_message_is_displayed() throws Throwable {
    List<Map<String, Object>> invoiceDocuments = dbHelperInvoices.getInvoiceDocumentsFilePath(testData.getInt("orderRef"));
    if (invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("jobSheetFilePath") == null && invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("invoiceFilePath") != null) {
        assertTrue("Unexpected error message displayed", commonSteps.the_error_is_displayed(message));
```

My question is what should i use in the place of message variable ? Or what do I need to add to get message variable to work ? As this code is throwing an error. Hope this is enough information. I am new to coding so apologies if this is a daft question.

EDIT: My previous code for this was

```
public void an_upload_invoice_error_message_is_displayed() throws Throwable {
    List<Map<String, Object>> invoiceDocuments = dbHelperInvoices.getInvoiceDocumentsFilePath(testData.getInt("orderRef"));
    if (invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("jobSheetFilePath") == null && invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("invoiceFilePath") != null) {
        assertTrue("Unexpected error message displayed", runtimeState.uploadInvoiceDocumentPage.isUploadJobSheetErrorDisplayed());
        outputHelper.takeScreenshot();
    } else if (invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("invoiceFilePath") == null && invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("jobSheetFilePath") != null) {
        assertTrue("Unexpected error message displayed", runtimeState.uploadInvoiceDocumentPage.isUploadInvoiceErrorDisplayed());
        outputHelper.takeScreenshot();
    } else if (invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("invoiceFilePath") == null && invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("jobSheetFilePath") == null){
        assertTrue("Unexpected error message displayed", runtimeState.uploadInvoiceDocumentsPage.isUploadInvoiceErrorDisplayed());
        assertTrue("Unexpected error message displayed", runtimeState.uploadInvoiceDocumentsPage.isUploadJobsheetErrorDisplayed());
        outputHelper.takeScreenshot();
    }
}
```

However, I was told to change the code to call the method from CommonSteps.java above

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object of the Class where `the_error_is_displayed(String)` lives. Then you can use its methods in the `an_upload_invoice_error_message_is_displayed()` method.

You can create this object as a field to the class just underneith the class declaration, or within the `an_upload_invoice_error_message_is_displayed()` method.

If you're still stuck, paste the entire class where `an_upload_invoice_error_message_is_displayed()` lives.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912224/how-to-organize-helper-functions)

You need to make the method that you'd like to call - `the_error_is_displayed` in your case - a `public static` method. That way it can be called from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just hardcoding the value as I couldn't find any other way to pass the variable through. Not sure this is the best way but it will work for now. My code is below :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> invoiceDocuments = dbHelperInvoices.getInvoiceDocumentsFilePath(testData.getInt("orderRef"));
    if (invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("jobSheetFilePath") == null && invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("invoiceFilePath") != null) {
        commonSteps.the_error_is_displayed("Please select a Job Sheet to upload");
        outputHelper.takeScreenshot();
    } else if (invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("invoiceFilePath") == null && invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("jobSheetFilePath") != null) {
        commonSteps.the_error_is_displayed("Please select an Invoice to upload");
        outputHelper.takeScreenshot();
    } else if (invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("invoiceFilePath") == null && invoiceDocuments.get(0).get("jobSheetFilePath") == null){
        commonSteps.the_error_is_displayed("Please select a Job Sheet to upload");
        commonSteps.the_error_is_displayed("Please select an Invoice to upload");
        outputHelper.takeScreenshot();
    }
```